# How to retrieve a stripe subscription id after a checkout session in a django project?

Tags: javascript, python, django, stripe-payments

Here is my problem. I made a stripe subscription for my django project, and I used the checkout session method. I would like to retrieve the stripe subscription id, after the payment, to put it on my customer model, so I can make a cancel subscription method for the customer, because the method given by stripe require to have this id :

```
stripe.Subscription.modify(
  *sub_id*,
  cancel_at_period_end=True
)
```

or

```
stripe.Subscription.delete(*sub_id*)
```

The problem is that I can't find the id anywhere else than in my stripe account, where I have every informations I can need, but I can't find how to retrieve it through code after the payment has been done.
I need to fill the field 'stripe_sub_id' in my customer model so i can make the cancel method work.

Here is the method that creates the checkout session

```
@csrf_exempt
def create_checkout_session(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        domain_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'
        stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
        try:
            checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
                success_url=domain_url + 'projets/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
                cancel_url=domain_url + 'projets/cancelled/',
                payment_method_types=['card'],
                mode='subscription',
                line_items=[
                    {
                        'price': sub_price_id,
                        'quantity': 1,
                    }
                ]
            )

            return JsonResponse({'sessionId': checkout_session['id']})
        except Exception as e:
            return JsonResponse({'error': str(e)})
```

And here is my script to activate the session

```
//Get stripe publishable key
fetch("/projets/config/")
.then((result) => { return result.json(); })
.then((data) => {
  // Initialize Stripe.js
  const stripe = Stripe(data.publicKey);
  console.log('fetch 1 reached'); //console check
  //Event handler
  document.querySelector("#payBtn").addEventListener("click", () => {
      // Get Checkout Session ID
      fetch("/projets/create-checkout-session/")
      .then((result) => { return result.json(); })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        // Redirect to Stripe Checkout
        return stripe.redirectToCheckout({sessionId: data.sessionId})
      })
      .then((res) => {
          console.log(res);
      });
  });
});
```

Hope I gave enough informations, thanks in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 6):

While you should always listen to `checkout.session.completed` [webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders#handle-the---event) to take internal actions, you can also optionally receive the Checkout session ID in the `success_url` using a [custom query parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/custom-success-page#modify-success-url).

With this ID, you can then [retrieve the session](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/retrieve) from your server and use [expansion](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects) to include the `subscription` details with `expand[]=subscription`.